# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, typeerror

How can I copy a file to another file?

The code I’m using is:

```
FileX = open("X.txt","r")
FileY = open("Y.txt","w")
X = FileX
FileY.write(FileX)
FileX.close()
FileY.close()
```

Which gives the error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Read all content of `X.txt` and write into `Y.txt`?

Comment: `FileX` is a file object, you are writing a file object to `FileY`, `FileY.write` takes `str` not file object.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the contents of file X into file Y?

Answer (score 11):

`FileX` is currently a file pointer, not the context of `X.txt`. To copy everything from `X.txt` to `Y.txt`, you will need to use `FileX.read()` to write the read content of `FileX`:

```
FileY.write(FileX.read())
```

Perhaps you should also look into using a `with` statement,

```
with open("X.txt","r") as FileX, open("Y.txt","w") as FileY:
    FileY.write(FileX.read())
# the files will close automatically
```

And also as suggested by a comment, you should use the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html) module for copying files and/or directories,

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('X.txt', 'T.txt')
# use shutil.copy2 if you want to make an identical copy preserving all metadata
```

Comment: Or better: `shutil.copy(x, y)`

Comment: thanks, the second solution with "import shutil" is working. But the first solution, with **`FileY.write(FileX.read())`** is not workin. I copy the code, I renamed both txt files, but instead of copy the content from one to another, is deleted the content from the first file. Did I forgot to import something?

Answer (score -3):

> str = FileX.readLines()
>
> FileY.write(str)

, pass string instead of the File

Comment: 'file' object has no attribute 'readLines', but 'readline', and the method readline() reads one entire line from the file.

Comment: Also, using `str` as a variable name is not recommended, since it shadows the entire [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str)-class.

Comment: Guess I need to practice my python more, thanks for the corrections!

Comment: file objects does not have a method named `readLines` but instead it have a method named `readlines`, it returns a list of lines that is read from `readline` until EOF is raised, which basically is just a list of all the lines in the file, but this is not valid in this current context because you **can not** pass a list as an argument to the `write` method of a file object. And you should **NEVER** name your variable `str` or any built-in methods. Btw, `readlines` does not return a str whatsoever